# How to make a button fade after clicked for iOS / xcode?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to make a button fade away after it is clicked. I know that I can use

```
_myButon.hidden = TRUE;
```

...to completely hide a button, but it feels abrupt and jarring. I also know I could sequentially lower the alpha or something, but wasn't sure how to make this happen automatically over a short period of time.

Can someone please give me a tip how to fade out a button after it is clicked using the simplest means possible? I want the effect to look something like a simple "Fade-out" from a powerpoint presentation or something :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use the objective-c tag unless it concerns actual language features.  This is a question specifically about how to do something on iOS.

Comment: http://maniacdev.com/2009/07/code-snippet-easy-fading-iphone-buttons-images-views please check the link

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/48888/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    _myButton.alpha = 0;
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than removing the button, just hide it. Taking all the suggestions into account you get:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{ _myButton.alpha = 0; }
                  completion:^(BOOL finished){ _myButton.hidden = YES; }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
_myButton.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

alternatively

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    _myButton.alpha = 0.0f;
}];
```

Comment: These methods are not recommended since iOS 4. You should use the block based methods instead.

Comment: @rdelmar it's just as good as using block animations and it'll support iOS < 4, just in more lines of code

Comment: If Apple recommends against using something, I think it's probably best to heed their advice -- I'm guessing that the old methods will be depreciated sometime in the future. Also, why would you want to support something older than iOS 4? That seems pretty pointless these days.

Comment: Can someone please explain this new "bock method"?

Comment: Blocks are a language-level feature added to C, Objective-C and C++, which allow you to create distinct segments of code that can be passed around to methods or functions as if they were values. Blocks are Objective-C objects, which means they can be added to collections like NSArray or NSDictionary. They also have the ability to capture values from the enclosing scope, making them similar to closures or lambdas in other programming languages. And read this URL  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Just reducing the alpha is not going to make your button completely be removed from your view. To a user it will look like its gone but its still there. They potentially still could accidently click it without knowing. So what you can do is do a timer to remove it from view after it has faded away.

```
...
  //alpha animation

//remove from view
    timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(hideMyButton) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

    -(IBAction) hideMyButton
    {
           [_myButon removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: Removing the button is generally not needed and even if you really wanted to do that, you'd probably not use a timer, but rather just do it in the completion block of `animationWithDuration`.

Comment: That's not true. When alpha = 0 (or less than a certain very small threshold), the button will be completely disabled.